# How to redirect to another view from controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I want to redirect to a view after I post a function from controller. Here is my codes:

```
 function CreateCollectivePdf() {
        var objectList = $(".hdnProductId");    
        var selectedProductIdList = '';    
        $(".hdnProductId").each(function (index) {
            var singleElement = objectList[index];
            selectedProductIdList += singleElement.value + ',';
        });

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: '@Url.Action("CreateEBulletinPdf","EBulletin")',
            contentType: "application/json",
            dataType: "JSON",
            data: JSON.stringify({ "productIdList": selectedProductIdList }),
            success: function (result) {

            }
        });

    }
```

Controller :

```
  public RedirectToRouteResult CreateEBulletinPdf(string productIdList)
        {
            try
            {
                productIdList = productIdList.Substring(0, productIdList.Length - 1);

                var productIdStrings = productIdList.Split(',');


                detailViewModels = productIdStrings.Select(productIdString => PdfProduct(Convert.ToInt32(productIdString))).ToList();


                return RedirectToAction("ProductsEBulletin");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

                throw;
            }
        }
public ActionResult ProductsEBulletin(List<ProductDetailViewModel> _detailViewModels)
    {
        try
        {
            return View(_detailViewModels);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {

            throw;
        }
    }
```

There is no exception but my ProductsEBulletin view wont be shown. Do you have any idea where is my mistake?

Comment: You are posting using ajax, then you should trigger the redirect at the browser. The ajax request doesn't get any clue about the server redirection, you will only receive the result from the first request

Answer (score 0):

Well, you've gotta do something in this `success` AJAX function. Right now you've left it blank, so you cannot possibly expect something to happen:

```
success: function (result) {

}
```

You probably want to show this resulting html somewhere in your DOM in order to see the results popping up somewhere. For example inject it in some container:

```
success: function (result) {
    $('#someDivId').html(result);
}
```

Now of course showing entire HTML with header inside a div element will break your DOM. You probably want to return only a partial view from your server in this case without including the entire Layout:

```
public ActionResult ProductsEBulletin(List<ProductDetailViewModel> _detailViewModels)
{
    return PartialView(_detailViewModels);
}
```

You can also notice that I have removed the useless try/catch statement from your `ProductsEBulletin` action because all it was doing at the moment was propagating the exception which is not very constructive.

OK, now only this partial will be injected into some container that you need to place somewhere in your DOM:

```
<div id="someDivId"></div>
```

This being said, if you need to redirect to an entirely new location, then probably AJAX is not something that you should have used in the first place but rather a standard HTML form postback.

Answer (score 0):

Your view won't be shown because the ajax function is not capable of getting the view response and then displaying it to the browser. I usually solve this by creating a form that posts to your controller's url. Before sending, you can programatically add an input to a form in your CreateCollectivePdf() function and then submit it so you can process your comma separated values in your function and then render your view.